# Perfect reconstruction of 2 channel filter bank

Tags: filters, wavelet, reconstruction, filter-bank

I am studying **Perfect reconstruction of 2 channel filter bank** for using **Biorthogonal Spline wavelet** for decomposing ECG signal. I am using **[Wavelets and Filter Banks By Gilbert Strang, Truong Nguyen](https://books.google.de/books?id=Z76N_Ab5pp8C&lpg=PA15&dq=find%20coefficient%20of%20low%20pass%20and%20high%20pass%20filter&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q&f=false)** to study perfect reconstruction. I am trying to understand the remove distortion condition, and it is given as:

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:updated_no_dist} 
{P_0(z) - P_0(-z) =  2z^{-k}}
\end{equation}

Now,it states, they need to design a low pass filter which satisfy the above equation, and to design a low-pass filter, they use this equation.

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:updated_no_distortion} 
 {P_0(z) = (1 + z^{-1})^{2p}Q(z)}
 \end{equation}
where p can be any integer and $Q(z)$ a polynomial of degree $2p-2$.

They use $p = 2$ and $Q(z) = -1 + 4z^{-1} - z^{-2}$. I am unable to find the reason why they use $p=2$ and where from the equation $Q(z)$ comes and what is the reason to use that exact equation. I read other papers as well, but I didn't find any reason for choosing $p=2$.

The other question is, what is the relationship between **perfect reconstruction** and **Biorthogonal Spline wavelet**.

It would be great if someone can explain this.

Comment: As far as I understand, the author just uses $p=2$ and $Q(z) = -1 + 4z^{-1} - z^{-2}$ to get Daubechies maxflat product filter with $N=2$. It's just an example, not a generic choice.

Comment: @Tendero Thanks for the comment. I want to understand, what will happen if I choose $p=1$ or $p=3$? and how the $Q(z)$ will be changed. What is $N$ here by the way? Order?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the nomenclature. $2N$ would be the number of zeros at $z=-1$. Regarding how $Q(z)$ changes with $p$, if you want to get the same filter that specific examples shows then you just have to solve the equation $$\frac{1}{16}(-1+9z^{-2}+16z^{-3}+9z^{-4}-z^{-6}) = (1 + z^{-1})^{2p}Q(z)$$

Fix a value of $p$, and then find $Q(z)$ such that the equality holds.

Comment: Will the left-hand side remain same for all the cases? I thought it is only when  $p=2$ and $Q(z)=-1+4z^{-1}-z^{-2}$ have chosen, then it will yields that result.

Comment: As I said before, the left side of the equation corresponds to a specific filter known as Daubechies maxflat product filter (judging by the book you provided). It's just an example the author uses.

Comment: Here $p=2$ means that is it quadratic spline wavelet?